# How to clip off the image if its outside bounds react native

Tags: ios, image, react-native

I'm new to react native development. I want the image to be in aspect ratio and when I try to change its bounds the area outside the bounds should be clipped off. In Android, it is working correctly but not in iOS the image is not clipping to its bounds and showing the whole image.

```
<View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#04894a",
        padding: 10,
        height: 110,
        alignItems: "center"
      }}
    >
 <View
        style={{
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{ height: 150, width: 150 }}
          source={require("../images/wow_logo.png")}
        />
      </View>
```

The image is going outside the view but still, it is showing in full. I want it to be cropped if going outside the bounds. Can anyone help me with this? Any links or suggestions are also appreciated.
TIA

Comment: try `overflow:'hidden'` in the image or the image parent view

Comment: @Coyote Thankx so much! I was trying overflow: false. Silly me!

Comment: so where it ended up in the image style or the view style?

Comment: @Coyote In the view style

Answer (score 11):

Use `overflow: hidden` - by default in react native the overflow flag is visible.

Also to maintain the aspect ratio, just have one parameter width or height to the image, then add `style={{ aspectRatio: 3/2 }}` so that the width:height ratio is maintained.

Comment: I had no idea the aspectRatio property existed. I used it and solved so much unnecessary code thanks